# Delete the duplicate rows in the table without creating CTE table at data bricks SQL

Tags: databricks-sql

I want to delete duplicate records in Drug table. The table contains the columns Pat_id, Drug_name, Purchase_date, Disease. It is a huge dataset, so I don't want to create any new/CTE table to drop the duplicates.

I tried the below query, but it deletes all the records of Pat_id including unique records.

```sql
%sql
DELETE
FROM Table1
WHERE pat_id NOT IN
(
SELECT MAX (pat_id)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY ALL having count (*)>1)
```

```sql
DELETE Table1
FROM Table1 t
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT *, COUNT (*) as Cnt
   FROM Table1 t
   GROUP BY ALL
   HAVING COUNT (*) > 1
) Duplicates
ON t.[pat_id] = Duplicates. [pat_id] AND 
t. [Drug_name] = Duplicates. [Drug_name] AND 
t. [Purchase_date] = Duplicates. [Purchase_date] AND 
t. [Disease] = Duplicates. [Disease]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE ROWID NOT IN (SELECT MIN(ROWID) FROM table1 GROUP BY column1,column2
```